# Excel Macro: Apply sorting to each sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Here is the code that I am using to apply sorting to each page except two. The system is throwing following error.
"select method of range class failed".

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
      Dim ws1 As Worksheet

```
For Each ws1 In Worksheets
    If ws1.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws1.Name <> "Extra" Then

**ws1.Range("A1:V1000").Select**      Something is wrong here I suspect

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1).Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I2:I1000") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("T2:T1000") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1).Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:V1000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End If
Next ws1
```

End Sub

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would `Select` the worksheet before `Selecting` the range.  Replace:

```
ws1.Range("A1:V1000").Select
```

with:

```
ws1.Select
Range("A1:V1000").Select
```

You may not need these `Selections` if you use `.Range()` rather than `Range()` in the code that follows.  Also since `ws1` is a worksheet object,:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1)
```

should be replace with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1.Name)
```

*There may be other problems with code.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I changed it to  ...........................ws1.Select       ws1.Range("A1:V1000").Select         and also changed ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1)  to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1.Name)                        It works now

Comment: @Navy  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Navy - Note that `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ws1.Name)` can be shortened to `ws1`.

Comment: @YowE3K Good comment!